# Can't figure out url rewrite regex

Tags: regex, url, nginx, seo

What I need to do is, to achieve redirect

from

```
domain.net/detail.php/?name=tRpPRU9dqVQ
```

to

```
domain.net/detail/?name=tRpPRU9dqVQ
```

in NGINX configuration.

Can't figure out proper regex. BTW, url might be with http/https.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this:

```
<?php
$murl = "domain.net/detail.php/?name=tRpPRU9dqVQ"
echo preg_replace ("(https?://domain\.net/detail)\.php(/\?name=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)", "\0\1", $myurl)
?>
```

How do you want to achieve redirect ? Do you want to do it using PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule in your nginx configuration.

```
rewrite ^/detail.php/(.*)$ /detail/$1 redirect;
```

You can replace the `redirect` word at the end with `permanent` for a `301` permanent redirect code. You can find more details about this on [their documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).